# $\int_{a}^{b}f'=f(b)-f(a)=>\int_{a}^{b}\lim_{n->\infty}Diff_{\frac{1}{n}}f=\lim_{n->\infty}\int_{a}^{b}Diff_{\frac{1}{n}}f$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

I want to show that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable a.e. on $(a,b)$. Then

$\int_{a}^{b}f'=f(b)-f(a)=>\int_{a}^{b}\lim_{n->\infty}Diff_{\frac{1}{n}}f=\lim_{n->\infty}\int_{a}^{b}Diff_{\frac{1}{n}}f$

Definition: $Diff_{h}=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, the divided difference.

ATTEMPT:

By differentiability I know that $Diff_{\frac{1}{n}}f->f'$ pointwise a.e. on $(a,b)$. So if I can somehow show $f$ is absolutely continuous, then I will have the sequence of divided differences $(Diff_{\frac{1}{n}}f)_n$ uniformly integrable and by the Vitali Convergence Theorem I can pass the limit inside the integral. But from the information given, how can I show $f$ is absolutely continuous, or is that a faulty approach?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @daw I didn't put in the functional analysis tag?

Comment: It would be useful if you explained what is $Diff _{\frac 1 n} f$.

Comment: @AlexM. thx for your comment, I've edited the question with the definition.

Comment: There are two differences between the title and the body of the question: one is the equivalence versus implication, the other is that the left-hand side of the body misses an integral (and is meaningless): which one is correct?

Comment: @AlexM.Ah thx again, I've fixed it. I'm only working on the implication in one direction

Comment: Faulty approach!  Just assuming that $f$ is continuous, a.e. differentiable and that $\int_a^b f'=f(b)-f(a)$ won't give you absolute continuity.  But the right hand side of your identity is just a Riemann integral (with a limit in front) of a sequence of continuous functions.  Try computing it using your old calculus skills.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson thanks, that's exactly what I ended up doing, when I get a minute I'll try to post the answer.